# Small window when I add Toolbar Break

Tags: pyqt5, toolbar

I'm trying to add a second toolbar below the first. So I add added a toolbar break and it worked but now when I run the program the window is too small. What I do wrong?
I'm working in PyQt5 5.15.4

```
        self.navtb = QToolBar("Navigation")

        self.addToolBar(self.navtb)

        self.addToolBarBreak()

        self.fav = QToolBar("Bookmarks")

        self.addToolBar(self.fav)

        self.navtb.setMovable(False)
        self.fav.setMovable(False)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: In the code above you're just creating two tool bars, we don't know what else you do in the rest of your code. Have you read the link in my previous comment? Does the code above allow us to **reproduce** the problem? No. In fact, it's not even clear what is the problem: for instance, what do you mean by "too small"?